# Pass a string containing a function name and its arguments to another function.

Tags: c, string, function, introspection

I would like to pass a string to a function in C in which the function will parse out a function name, the arguments for the function, and its datatypes, and then call the function for me. What is the best approach?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to "make [a] string as a function call".

Comment: I'd love to help, but I can't make any sense out of your question. Please revise and try again.

Comment: @CodyGray and Jonathan Henson  i am working something on variable number of parameters.so in that for every different function call i'll get different list of parameters,so that is why i am forming a string with all the parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the behavior of `printf()`?

Comment: @CodyGray no,this is a part of my JNI code

Comment: JohnKrishna, that doesn't really answer his question. The language and use is irrelevant. What he means is, are you trying to write a function that takes a format string for the first parameter, and a variable number of arguments which will be specified in the format string?

Comment: @JonathanHenson no i am not writing anything which makes use of format string.

Comment: The tool that "makes strings into function calls" is generally some kind of *compiler*. If you want to support general C syntax, then you need a general C compiler. If you want to support a more limited syntax, then you'll have to define *exactly* what that is, and write a small compiler for that.

Comment: If you want to do such things on a regular basis, you'd better use a language with `eval` (such as JavaScript, for example). C is not quite suitable for this, unless you're ok with something like `CINT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a function with a format string and variable arguments like:

```
int function(const char* strFormat, ... )
{
  //parse out the format using regex or something
  //then store the data into the variable aruments
  //or create a string concatenating everything
}
```

like, say printf, sprintf, or scanf does,

then the best thing for you to do is look at some good tutorials.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhdxye9(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

If you are wanting to actually pass a function name for the function to call, along with its arguments, you either need to implement some form of reflection or introspection in your c code, a really complex switch statement which calls the functions for you based upon the string value, or write some complex macros to act as a sort of a secondary 
compiler.

glib's gobject is an excellent example of introspection in c.
http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/

something simple without introspection may be:

```
void* function (const char* strFunctionName, ... )
{
  if(!strcmp(strFunctionName, "functionA"))
  {
    //use va_list to parse out the arguments for the function.
    functionA(//each of the arguments from va_list);
  }
  else if(!strcmp(strFunctionName, "functionB"))
  {
    //use va_list to parse out the arguments for the function.
    functionB(//args from va_list);
  }
  ...
}
```

If you have something more specific in mind, please specify in your question.

Comment: thanks for your time,but you didn't get my question.i am not trying a function with variable number of arguments.what i am trying is suppose i have a string char *str="variance(dArray,p1,p2)".how to make this string as a normal function call

Comment: @johnkrishna Using variable arguments will make the parsing of the datatypes and their values much easier than writing an incredibly complex regex to do it.

Comment: thank you very much once again but we both are are on different tracks it seems.in my scenario every time string will keep change,depending on the parameters i receive,so i just need how to make my C compiler to treat my string as a function call.

Comment: @johnkrishna Without writing your own compiler, you can't. One of my three options is your only option. You will have to write a function to execute the function specified in the string for you. for example:

 const char* strFunction = "MyFunction(a, b)";
 ExecuteMyFunctionPlease(strFunction);

 There is no way that I know of to get around this.

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct.but what if the value of strFunction changes?

Comment: You will have to enforce a contract in your code that says that any function that expects to be callable dynamically i.e. from a string, has to make sure it is implemented in whatever function you write to handle this. I have already explained your three options for doing this, making sure it is implemented is up to you.

Comment: @johnkrishna The implementation I put in my answer is probably the easiest.

Comment: your answered helped me a lot,though this is not an exact answer for this question,marking it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is standard, but you could use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in C++.

e.g:

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
void foo(int, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make:

```
char *funct = "foo(bar)";
```

to actually call the function `foo()`, then its impossible, C just doesn't work that way. I would recommend that:

a) you sit down and rethink your application, because such behaviour shouldn't be needed for anything.

b) try a language with such capabilities, such as objective-c

c) if you really, really, really wanna do it... then make a string parser and lots of if's, or function pointers. Something in the lines of:

1. Get string in the form of "function(var1, var2, ..., varN)"
2. Get the name of the function (ie. everything before '(' )
3. Get all the parameters (`strtok()` for example)
4. Identify the function comparing constant names with your string ( `strcmp()` )
5. If the parameters are numeric ( `isdigit()` or `sscanf( string, "%d", &parameter ) > 0` ) convert them to a usable primitive (`atoi()`, `atof()`, etc or `sscanf()`)
6. Pass the params to your function.

Comment: thank you.i think your option c will be helpful for me.is there a way in C++?

Comment: @johnkrishna There is no way to do this in any language that doesn't support reflection. Your c-like options if you want to do this are Java, Objective-C or C#. Or you could implement the reflection yourself in c or in c++.

Comment: @whitlionV here the parameters of the function will keep change,in that case how to identify the types(because strtok() will give all of them as strings)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a code from a string (I'm just guessing, your question is hard to understand), then there are many options available: from embedding the whole Clang and LLVM into your code (and making sure its JIT is aware of all your declarations you're going to export) to embedding a simple scripting language (like Lua or Guile) and providing wrappers for all the functions you want to call this way.

Comment: ya i want to execute the method which is in string.but this is in C/C++.to understand my question properly see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156389/how-to-parse-a-string-so-that-compiler-executes-the-statements-inside

Comment: No, your question is still very far from being clear. And, btw., `Clang` is a C compiler. You may also want to try embedding `tcc` (it is made specifically for this purpose), it is much smaller and faster than clang.